# Can a receive port be triggered on 2 diffrent reasons

Tags: biztalk

I have normal receive port using a WCF-Adapter for oracle that uses a polling query. Now the problem is that the receive port not only needs to run once the polling query has a hit, but also once per day, regardless of the polling-statement.

Is there a way to make it possible without creating the entire process again?

Comment: Can you describe the problem you trying to addresss?  If you are Polling (what I assume you mean by trigger as neither SQL Adapter supports SQL Triggers) and the interval is less than a day, it will always run at least once per day.  If you mean Notifications, that is fundamentally different than Polling so a daily operation would have to be created on it's own.

Comment: It's a WCF adapter for oracle. It is polling, not trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way will be to use an additional receive location. So you will end up with one receive port that contains two receive locations, one for each query.

In the past I have done this with the WCF adapter when polling SQL Server. The use of two locations did require duplicating the schema, unfortunately, to account for the different namespaces. You will probably need two different (and essentially identical) schemas as well.

[WCF-SQL polling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd788409.aspx) locations require distinct *InboundId* values while [WCF Oracle polling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd787819.aspx) (as you have noted in the comments) requires different a *PollingId* for each receive location.

The ESB toolkit includes pipeline components to [remove and add namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff699608%28v=bts.80%29.aspx), if you need additional downstream applications work with only a single schema on the messages coming from both locations and/or do not also want to duplicate a BizTalk map.

Comment: I agree with this answer. You can reuse any custom pipeline you made within the second receive location.

Comment: The problem i have with this solution, is the pollingID.  The pollingID has to be unique for every location but changing the pollingID gives an error on the receive pipeline (Reason: Finding the document specification by message type). How do you avoid this?

Comment: I edited my answer with information on this. We had to have two different schemas, one for each message type. It's not a perfectly ideal situation, but seems to be the best one possible.

Comment: I have been working on this and seem to always have a problem with the routing. i have made it so the orchestration has a filter on the receive_port name. i have triple checked and i have made no typos in the receiveport name, so is there any reason the orchestration wouldn't pick these up? or is filtering on the receiveport name only not enough?

Comment: is there actually a tutorial or guide on using two such locations for 1 port? i googled it and find nothing on the subject.

Comment: To setup 2 receive locations for 1 port, open the receive port configuration and add both locations there.  
Ensure that the value for the receive port name in the orchestration's filter expression is wrapped in double quotation marks. You can also  use something else like the message types of the 2 schemas that correspond to each receive location, with the Group By column set to _Or_. Just be careful that the orchestration does not produce messages of the same types, causing an infinite loop.  Additionally, verify that your receive port is actually receiving messages in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Change your polling statement so that it has an OR CURRENT_TIME() BETWEEN ....
That way it will trigger at the time you want.